# How to give dynamic value in terms of % in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a jQuery by dynamic value.Unfortunately it didn't work

This one works below

```
$("#colorSlider").css({ background:"-webkit-linear-gradient(left, black 50%, white 50%)"  });
```

When I want to make that percentage values by my hand it didn't work.Here what I tried below

```
$("#colorSlider").css({ background:"-webkit-linear-gradient(left, black"+ 50+"%, white"+ 50+"%)"  });
```

Comment: `"black"+ 50+"%"` = `black50%` and NOT `black 50%`. You're missing a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#colorSlider").css({ background:"-webkit-linear-gradient(left, black "+ 50+"%, white "+ 50+"%)"  });
```

you need to add space after the color string directly before the double quotes

Comment: shouldn't background be `"background"`?

Comment: @OliverHeward why? There is no difference, it's just an object literal. Whether you have the key in quotes or not only matters if you have stuff like spaces or dashes and similar there. Since this is a perfectly valid identifier to use, you can omit the quotes.

Comment: @OliverHeward quotes aren't required in object keys, you only need them if the key contains invalid characters for a property name (such as ` ` or `-`). It's only JSON which requires everything to be in double quotes.